# Google sheets: how to add links to individual results of importxml function?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm using the following equation to search twitter handles:

`=transpose(importxml(F1, "//span/a"))`

Where F1 is: https://twitter.com/search?f=users&vertical=default&q=from%3A**PERSON_NAME**&src=typd

This returns a lot of results (depending on how many handles there are), but I would like each result to be a link to twitter so I can easily verify if the handle is for the person I am looking for.

I have tried variations of this:

`=transpose(concatenate("http://twitter.com/",importxml(F2, "//span/a")))`

But the result is this: http://twitter.com/@handle1@handle2@handle3

So that's not useful. I need http://twitter.com/@handle1, http://twitter.com/@handle2, etc.

Is there a way of adding a link to each returned result?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of concatenate you can use "&" to join string ("A"&"B" = "AB"), and using arrayformula to join in a recursive way for each item in importXml output

```
=transpose(arrayformula("http://twitter.com/" & importxml(F2, "//span/a")))
```

Hope that helps